# How to determine if a point K(lat,lng) is on a simple polyline from A(lat,lng) to B(lat,lng) in Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I have a polyline in google maps from point A(lat,lng) to B(lat,lng). If someone gives me a point K(lat,lng) and say that it is on the polyline from A (lat,lng) to B(lat,lng) or B(lat,lng) to A(lat,lng) then how can I determine it is true? I am thinking about something as the following :

```
if A.lat <= K.lat AND B.lat >= K.lat OR B.lat <= K.lat AND A.lat >= K.lat then 
        K is on the line
    else 
        K is not on the line
```

Should this logic work? I am asking because in my test, mostly it worked but some rare cases it did not work even though the point was actually taken from the line.

NB : Using Google Map Javascrpt API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documenation for `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly):

```
isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)
boolean 
Computes whether the given point lies on or near to a polyline, or the edge of a polygon, within a specified tolerance. Returns true when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance. The tolerance defaults to 10-9 degrees.
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwnch0k5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
      clickable: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(e) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: e.latLng,
          map: map,
          draggable: true
      });
      var contentStr;
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(marker.getPosition(), flightPath, 1e-5)) {
          contentStr = "on line";
      } else { 
          contentStr = "not on line";
      }
      marker.contentStr = contentStr;
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e) {
          infowindow.setContent(this.contentStr+"<br>"+this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+"<br><a href='javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng("+this.getPosition().toUrlValue()+"));map.setZoom(19);'>Zoom In</a>");
          infowindow.open(map,this);
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(this.getPosition(), flightPath, 1e-5)) {
          contentStr = "on line";
        } else { 
          contentStr = "not on line";
        }
        this.contentStr = contentStr;
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
  });
      
    
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```